# Best way to keep column value up to date

Tags: postgresql, triggers

I have the following tables (simplified) :
[image]

[image]

They are connected with a foreign key  ( element_id). If all acquisition entries of an element have a delivery_time which is greater than 28,  the element gets the status critical. At the moment i use a view 
based on the elements table which checks for every element_id if it is critical. The function i use reads out the min(dilvery_time) of an element and checks if it is greater than 28. This calculation is done every time the view is opened.

The soltution works, but it's  slow. Also i think the approach above does much unnecessary work, because the critical status can only changes if the table acquisition is modified.

My new approach would be to add a boolean column "critical" to the elements table. Also i would set up a trigger function on the acquisitions table which updates the critical status of the modified element (if necessary). Then the critical status should always be up to date and the selects should be much faster.

Is my new approach suitable, or are there better ways to solve my problem ?

Edit, here are the create statemens of the tables,view and function:

```
CREATE TABLE elements (
element_id serial primary key,
elemnt_name varchar(100));

CREATE TABLE acquisitions (
acquisition_id serial primary key,
element_id int NOT NULL,
delivery_time int,
foreign key (element_id) references elements(element_id));

CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION is_element_critical(param integer)
RETURNS boolean AS
$BODY$
DECLARE
delivery_date_int integer;
BEGIN
SELECT into delivery_date_int min(delivery_time) 
from acquisitions where   element_id  = param;
IF delivery_date_int > 28 THEN
RETURN true;
ELSE
return false;
END IF;
END
$BODY$
LANGUAGE plpgsql VOLATILE;

CREATE OR REPLACE VIEW elementview AS 
SELECT elements.element_id,
elements.elemnt_name, is_element_critical(elements.element_id)  
AS is_element_critical
FROM elements;
```

With ~10000 acquisitions and ~ 1500 elements a select on the elementview takes 1600 ms.

Comment: Rather than posting a screenshot of some GUI, you should post the `CREATE TABLE` statements for those tables. Or even better: create an example on http://sqlfiddle.com You might also want to post query you are using now, maybe it can be improved (see here for some tips on how to post performance questions: http://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/SlowQueryQuestions )

Comment: You are talking about demormalization. Avoid it if you can. Prefer seeking improvement to your query if possible. Perhaps post the query and ask "why is it slow" - there maybe a simple improvement that can speed it up.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One problem with your approach is that the function is evaluated for each row in the view.

You could try to use a join and process this in a set-based manner (which is very often a better approach than a row-by-row processing).

```
CREATE OR REPLACE VIEW elementview 
AS 
SELECT e.element_id, 
       e.elemnt_name, 
       min(a.delivery_time)  > 28 as is_element_critical
FROM elements e
  JOIN acquisitions a ON a.element_id = e.element_id
GROUP BY e.element_id, e.elemnt_name;
```

Adding an index on `acquisitions(element_id, delivery_time)` might speed up this query.

If you don't have an acquisition for each element you might want to change this to an `LEFT JOIN`.

If the number of acquisitions that are not critical is much lower than those that are critical, you might be able to speed this up even further using a partial index:

```
create index idx_ac on acquisitions (element_id, delivery_time)
  where delivery_time > 28;
```

And then only join against acquisitions that are critical:

```
SELECT e.element_id, 
       e.elemnt_name, 
       min(a.delivery_time) > 28 as is_element_critical
FROM elements e
  LEFT JOIN acquisitions a ON a.element_id = e.element_id and a.delivery_time > 28
GROUP BY e.element_id, e.elemnt_name;
```

The left join is necessary because of the added condition `and a.delivery_time > 28`.

On my laptop the first query runs in 35ms (2000 elements, 30000 acquisitions). The second one runs in 5ms. Every element has at least one acquisition that is critical (which is probably not really realistic)

Comment: I guess it should be  min(a.delivery_time)  rather than min(e.delivery_time).

Comment: @Akkusativobjekt: yes that was a typo. Please see my edit. There is even more room for improvement (but it depends on the data).

Comment: I tested your first approach and it only took 100 ms, which is a great result (i added another join to have all columns like in the old view).And yes there are much less critical elements than non critical. I will give the approach with the index a try.

Comment: I misread, there are much less critical elements than non critical.Can i just reverse the statement of the index?

Comment: @Akkusativobjekt: I would keep the order of the columns as they are (as that helps the join). In that case you probably just don't want the `where` clause. But do play around with it and check the execution plan: it will tell you which indexing strategy is more efficient.